# Best-case Running-time to solve an NP-Complete problem?

Tags: language-agnostic, theory, complexity-theory, performance, np-complete

What is the fastest algorithm that exists up with to solve a particular NP-Complete problem? For example, a naive implementation of [travelling salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) is O(n!), but with dynamic programming it can be done in O(n^2 * 2^n). Is there any perhaps "easier" NP-Complete problem that has a better running time?

I'm curious about exact solutions, not approximations.

Comment: I'll +1, I'm interested to see what others see.

Comment: Your question asks "What is the fastest algorithm we've come up with?"  And then "Note I'm not interested in approximations, but exact solutions."  How can we know the exact fastest algorithm that **you've** come up with?

Comment: Have you tried http://mathoverflow.net/?

Comment: @RickNZ: By 'we' I meant 'humanity in general'. I'm not trying to have you guys beat my algorithm, I just want to know what the fastest is that exists.

Comment: mathoverflow version: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6418/best-case-running-time-to-solve-an-np-complete-problem

Comment: I am not quite sure, but isn't O(2^n*n^2) == O(2^n)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] with dynamic programming it can be done in O(n^2 * 2^n). Is there any perhaps "easier" NP-Complete problem that has a better running time?

Sort of. You can get rid of any polynomial factor by creating an artificial problem that encodes the same solution in a polynomially larger input. As long as the input is only polynomially larger, the resulting problem is still NP-complete. Since the complexity is by definition the function that maps input size to running time, if the input size grows the function gets into lower O classes.

So, the same algorithm running on TSP with the input padded with n^2 useless bits, will have complexity O(1 * 2^sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 4):

A characteristic of the NP-Complete problems is that any of the problems in NP can be mechanically transformed into any of the NP-Complete problems in, at most, polynomial time.

Therefore, whatever the best solution for any given NP-Complete problem is, it is automatically a similarly-good solution for any other NP problem.

Given that dynamic programming can solve Traveling Salesman Problem in 2^n time and 2^n space, the same must be true of all other NP problems [well, plus the time to apply the transformation, I guess - so it could be 2^(n+1)].

Comment: I think it only requires O(n) space

Comment: I didn't remember off-hand, so I looked it up on Wikipedia. Could be that I misread the article...

Answer (score 0):

Generally you cannot find the *best* solution for the generic Travelling Salesman problem without trying all combinations (there might be negative distances, etc).

By adding additional restrictions and loosening the requirement of getting the *best* solution, you can speed up things quite a bit.

For instance you can get polynomial executable time if the distances in the problem obey the "it is not longer to go directly from A to B than going from A to C to B" (i.e. a shortcut is never longer), *and* you can live with the result maximally being 1.5 times the optimal value.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Metric_TSP